# The code isn't showing the book. I tried my best but never succeeded, please help me with it

Tags: java, android, xml, epub, epublib

this is my code (MainActivity1.java)

```
    package com.example.folowreader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Book;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Resource;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.TOCReference;
 import nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


  public class MainActivity1 extends ListActivity {


    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<RowData> contentDetails;

    Intent intent ;
    public static final String BOOK_NAME = "austen-pride-and-prejudice-illustrations.epub"; 
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);





    contentDetails = new ArrayList<RowData>();
   // myClass((Context) this.getActivity());

   AssetManager  assetManager = getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream epubInputStream = assetManager.open(BOOK_NAME);
        Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);
        logContentsTable(book.getTableOfContents().getTocReferences(), 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("epublib", e.getMessage());
    } 

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.main2,
            R.id.textView3, contentDetails);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true); 
  }

    private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData>{

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {
        super((Context) context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        private View row;
        private TextView titleHolder = null;

        public ViewHolder(View row) {
            super();
            this.row = row;
        }

        public TextView getTitle() {
            if(null == titleHolder)
                titleHolder = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            return titleHolder;
        }
     }

      @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        TextView title = null;
        RowData rowData = getItem(position);
        if(null == convertView){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main2, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        title = holder.getTitle();
        title.setText(rowData.getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }

    }

    private void logContentsTable(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth) {
    if (tocReferences == null) {
        return;
     }
     for (TOCReference tocReference:tocReferences) {
        StringBuilder tocString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            tocString.append("\t");
        }
        tocString.append(tocReference.getTitle());
        RowData row = new RowData();
        row.setTitle(tocString.toString());
        row.setResource(tocReference.getResource());
        contentDetails.add(row);
        logContentsTable(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1);
    }
    }

    private class RowData{
    private String title;
    private Resource resource;

    public RowData() {
        super();
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Resource getResource() {
        return resource;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    RowData rowData = contentDetails.get(position);
     intent = new Intent(MainActivity1.this, ContentViewActivity.class);

    try {


        intent.putExtra("display", new String(rowData.getResource().getData()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    startActivity(intent);

    }
```

this is my ContentViewActivity.java

```
    @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_view);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String displayString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("display");
    if(displayString != null)
        webView.loadData(displayString, "text/html", "utf-8");
  }
```

this is the XML of MainActivity1

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#ADD8E6"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="com.example.folowreader.MainActivity1" >



  <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5" >
 </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the XML of ContentViewActivity

```
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.folowreader.ContentViewActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight  = "true" 
    ></WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the XML of main2

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ADD8E6" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />



</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to change the name of the book by adding the path plus book name but nothing happened. the book isn't showing. The code is meant to make a list of the contents (Table of contents) and then to show the content of each row in a separate activity inside a webView. please help me, I need help.
I need to know how to make the code work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing I noticed was this:

```
if (tocReferences == null) {
    return;
}
```

Are you sure that

```
book.getTableOfContents().getTocReferences()
```

is not simply returning you a null-pointer?

Comment: For the purpose of testing I injected a line of toast:'if     (tocReferences == null) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity1.this, "It's     returning null",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return;
     }' and in the end it showed nothing so i guess that it is not returning a null pointer